# If Else Statement with logo in WordPress theme

Tags: php, wordpress, themes, wordpress-theming

Having trouble with this If Else statement. I can get get the logo to display without the statement, so everything is pathed correctly, but when I put the If Else statement in, it doesn't display either the logo or the H1 header.

Thanks in advance for any help.

```
<?php if ( $options['flaunt_one_logo'] != '' ) : ?>
        echo <a href="<?php bloginfo('url')?>/" class="<?php logo_container_class(); ?>"><img src="<?php echo get_option('flaunt_one_logo'); ?>" alt="<?php bloginfo('name')?>" />
    else
        echo <h1 id="site-title"><span><a href="<?php echo esc_url( home_url( '/' ) ); ?>" title="<?php echo esc_attr( get_bloginfo( 'name', 'display' ) ); ?>" rel="home"> <?php bloginfo( 'name' ); ?></a></span></h1>;

    <?php endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your echo is outside the php code.

Also read up on IF statements: http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.if.php

```
<?php if ( $options['flaunt_one_logo'] != '' ) { 
        echo "<a href=\"".bloginfo('url')."\" class=\"".logo_container_class()."\"><img src=\"".get_option('flaunt_one_logo')."\" alt=\"".bloginfo('name').">";
} else {
        echo "<h1 id=\"site-title\"><span><a href=\"".esc_url( home_url( '/' ) )."\" title=\"".esc_attr( get_bloginfo( 'name', 'display' ) )."\" rel=\"home\">".bloginfo( 'name' )."</a></span></h1>";
}
?>
```

Comment: Thank you. I'll have to spend some time boning up on it.

Using the code you've provided, I'm able to get the H1 to show up, but the logo is not displaying. There currently is a logo set in the options, so it should display.

Any thoughts?

Comment: I also noticed that the H1 isn't grabbing the CSS rule and is just staying small as if it were paragraph text.

Comment: Is get_option a function you have declared? Not sure how Wordpress works. Try $options['flaunt_one_logo'] instead of get_option('flaunt_one_logo').

Comment: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_option does suggest that get_option should work. If you put: <?php echo get_option('flaunt_one_logo'); ?> in your code, does it output the correct SRC to the logo?

Comment: Just realised the img tag was never closed. I have edited my answer.

Comment: No... same situation. The H1 is returned. I can share with you the section of my Functions.php file where the function is declared.

Comment: function get_logo_container_class() 
{
$logo_image_url = get_option('flaunt_one_logo');
$logo_image_path = str_replace(get_site_url() . '/', '', $logo_image_url);
$logo_container_class = 'flaunt-one-logo';

 if (file_exists($logo_image_path)) {
 list($logo_width, $logo_height) = getimagesize($logo_image_path);

 if ($logo_width > $logo_height) {
 $logo_container_class .= ' horizontal';
 } else {
 $logo_container_class .= ' vertical';
  }
 }
    
return $logo_container_class;
}

function logo_container_class() {
echo get_logo_container_class();
}

Comment: What do you get from: <?php echo $options['flaunt_one_logo']; ?>

Comment: You can't - it's best to edit your answer to add in extra code. Don't worry though, I don't need to see the functions file.

Comment: OK cool, I just input <?php echo $options['flaunt_one_logo']; ?> And it doesn't return anything.

Comment: Thats your problem then. The code says: If $options['flaunt_one_logo'] is not empty then show the logo. You could replace it with get_option('flaunt_one_logo')

Comment: Thanks for sticking with me here.
So when I do that, this is what I get: http://williambay.com/test/
The logo shows up, and the William Bay Photographic Arts is the H1 (still unstyled)...

Answer (score 0):

try this:
You also forgot to close your first `<a>` with a `</a>`

```
<?php if ( get_option('flaunt_one_logo', false) !== false ) : ?>
    <a href="<?php bloginfo('url')?>/" class="<?php logo_container_class(); ?>">
        <img src="<?php echo get_option('flaunt_one_logo'); ?>" alt="<?php bloginfo('name')?>" />
    </a>
<?php else ?>
    <h1 id="site-title">
        <span>
            <a href="<?php echo esc_url( home_url( '/' ) ); ?>" title="<?php echo esc_attr( get_bloginfo( 'name', 'display' ) ); ?>" rel="home">
            <?php bloginfo( 'name' ); ?>
            </a>
        </span>
    </h1>;
<?php endif; ?>
```